# alert(confirm('ok?')) can't work fine in WKWebview

Tags: wkwebview

error:

> Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting

it seems the `alert(confirm('ok?'));` style code trigger presenting a view controller simultaneously in WKWebview's delegate, is there any way to support this?

my html:

```
    <button onclick="alert(1);">alert</button><br>
    <button onclick="alert(confirm('ok?'));">confirm</button><br>
    <button onclick="alert(prompt('please input'));">text</button><br>
```

my code:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:%@", message);
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSLog(@"runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:%@, did clicked", message);
    }];
    [alert addAction:action];
    completionHandler();
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:%@", message);
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSLog(@"runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:%@, did clicked yes", message);
    }];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSLog(@"runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:%@, did click cancel", message);
    }];
    [alert addAction:action];
    [alert addAction:actionCancel];
    completionHandler(YES);
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my bad.

you should use `completionHandler` in every action callback, not just put it in delegate body, so it could be this:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:%@", message);
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"提示" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSLog(@"runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:%@, did clicked", message);
        completionHandler(YES);
    }];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSLog(@"runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:%@, did click cancel", message);
        completionHandler(NO);
    }];
    [alert addAction:action];
    [alert addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```